# save image to a png file using processing.js

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I have an small drawing application made in processing.js. I would like to save the image made using the application to a server using a php file (no problem on this).
I know the canvas element has a method to get that content, canvas.toDataURL() but I dont know how to do the same with processing.js

Any hint?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps

```
var image = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].toDataURL();
```

Comment: @Breton : actually, i have added one image using <img> element and drawn some lines on the image using javascript successfully.Now i want to save the modified image back to the server.In that case, shall i use your above answer to do that.. for example var image = document.getElementById("Image2").toDataURL("image/png");

Comment: the above function returns a data uri. you can post it back to the server via an XHR request. you could even place it as the value in a form. the only caveat is you must be prepared to do the appropriate decoding server side.

Answer (score 0):

So when you use saveFrame() in processing.js. The image opens in a new  window and i found it hard to intercept the data. The soultion is to get the image from the canvas in javascript.

```
// this grabs the canvas and turns it into a base64 image    
var image = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].toDataURL();

// Log the data to the canvas to check it working
console.log(image);

// then you can place the image on your web page    
document.getElementById("theImage").src=image;
```

Then the html is easy. Just add

```
<img id="theImage"></img>
```

If you want to upload the image to a server you can acsess the data in js with.

```
image
```

Note that you can also use style display:none; and have the canvas render image for you without the canvas displaying. It also supports transparent pngs and the canvas by default is transparent